# is there way to change recyclerview slob?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-scrollview

I saw a recyclerview in google play can scroll with 70 degree slob ( https://i.stack.imgur.com/co6DB.jpg) but in normal recyclerview you can scroll with 20 degree slob.
is there way to change the recyclerview slob?
or the library that solve this?
i found github project that did this but in kotlin. i need it with java

github project:
https://github.com/MalikDE/NestedRecyclerView

please check out the github link to better understanding question

Comment: 1) what do you mean by a slob? It seems a non-standard word. 2) Could you please edit your question a bit and capitalize your sentences and finish them with periods ('.' symbols)? "I" and "Java" are normally capitalized words in English. 3) If the answer below suits you, please accept that!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code
in Kotlin:

```
val editText: EditText = findViewById(R.id.yourEditText)
editText.requestFocus()
val inputManager = getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
handler.postDelayed({
    inputManager.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT)
}, 500)
```

in Java

```
EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.yourEditText);
editText.requestFocus();
InputMethodManager manager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
handler.postDelayed(() -> {
    manager.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
}, 500);
```